# Running nested for loops with Puppeteer page.$$eval(...)

Tags: puppeteer, eval

I have an html document with two levels of repeating html elements. The first level is a variable number of test questions (1 -> n), and then within each test question, there are a variable number of possible answers (2 -> n).

Using Puppeteer's page.$$eval(...) function, I need to iterate through these two levels and capture the data associated with each level.

I am able to capture the first level data (test questions), but am unable to figure out how to iterate through and capture the nested inner level (possible answers).

Here's what I have so far...

### Sample HTML:

```
<html>
<body>
<div id="8888" class="course-wrapper">
    <div class="question">
        <div class="q-label">Question 1</div>
        <div class="q-question">Is this question #2?</div>
        <div class="q-choices">
            <div class="choice">
                <div class="num">1.</div>
                <div class="answer">yes</div>
                <div class="answer-check">incorrect</div>
            </div>
            <div class="choice">
                <div class="num">2.</div>
                <div class="answer">no</div>
                <div class="answer-check">correct</div>
            </div>
            <div class="choice">
                <div class="num">3.</div>
                <div class="answer">perhaps</div>
                <div class="answer-check">incorrect</div>
            </div>
            <div class="choice">
                <div class="num">4.</div>
                <div class="answer">all of the above</div>
                <div class="answer-check">incorrect</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="question">
        <div class="q-label">Question 2</div>
        <div class="q-question">How far is it to Tipperary?</div>
        <div class="q-choices">
            <div class="choice">
                <div class="num">1.</div>
                <div class="answer">a long way</div>
                <div class="answer-check">correct</div>
            </div>
            <div class="choice">
                <div class="num">2.</div>
                <div class="answer">not so far</div>
                <div class="answer-check">incorrect</div>
            </div>
            <div class="choice">
                <div class="num">3.</div>
                <div class="answer">a very long way</div>
                <div class="answer-check">incorrect</div>
            </div>
            <div class="choice">
                <div class="num">4.</div>
                <div class="answer">right next door</div>
                <div class="answer-check">incorrect</div>
            </div>
            <div class="choice">
                <div class="num">5.</div>
                <div class="answer">just over the hill</div>
                <div class="answer-check">incorrect</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="question">
        <div class="q-label">Question 3</div>
        <div class="q-question">Is this question #3?</div>
        <div class="q-choices">
            <div class="choice">
                <div class="num">1.</div>
                <div class="answer">yes</div>
                <div class="answer-check">correct</div>
            </div>
            <div class="choice">
                <div class="num">2.</div>
                <div class="answer">no</div>
                <div class="answer-check">incorrect</div>
            </div>
            <div class="choice">
                <div class="num">3.</div>
                <div class="answer">perhaps</div>
                <div class="answer-check">incorrect</div>
            </div>
            <div class="choice">
                <div class="num">4.</div>
                <div class="answer">all of the above</div>
                <div class="answer-check">incorrect</div>
            </div>
            <div class="choice">
                <div class="num">5.</div>
                <div class="answer">i don't know</div>
                <div class="answer-check">incorrect</div>
            </div>
            <div class="choice">
                <div class="num">6.</div>
                <div class="answer">none of your business</div>
                <div class="answer-check">incorrect</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

### Target JSON:

```
[
  {
    "courseUNID": "8888",
    "qCount": 3,
    "qArray": [
      {
        "testQLabel": "Question 1",
        "testQ": "Is this question 2?",
        "testQAnswerChoiceCount": 4,
        "testQPossibleAnswers": [
          {
            "Num": "1.",
            "Answer": "yes",
            "AnswerCheck": "incorrect"
          },
          {
            "Num": "2.",
            "Answer": "no",
            "AnswerCheck": "correct"
          },
          {
            "Num": "3.",
            "Answer": "perhaps",
            "AnswerCheck": "incorrect"
          },
          {
            "Num": "4.",
            "Answer": "all of the above",
            "AnswerCheck": "incorrect"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "testQLabel": "Question 2",
        "testQ": "How far is it to Tipperary?",
        "testQAnswerChoiceCount": 5,
        "testQPossibleAnswers": [
          {
            "Num": "1.",
            "Answer": "a long way",
            "AnswerCheck": "correct"
          },
          {
            "Num": "2.",
            "Answer": "not so far",
            "AnswerCheck": "incorrect"
          },
          {
            "Num": "3.",
            "Answer": "a very long way",
            "AnswerCheck": "incorrect"
          },
          {
            "Num": "4.",
            "Answer": "right next door",
            "AnswerCheck": "incorrect"
          },
          {
            "Num": "5.",
            "Answer": "just over the hill",
            "AnswerCheck": "incorrect"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "testQLabel": "Question 3",
        "testQ": "Is this question 2?",
        "testQAnswerChoiceCount": 6,
        "testQPossibleAnswers": [
          {
            "Num": "1.",
            "Answer": "yes",
            "AnswerCheck": "incorrect"
          },
          {
            "Num": "2.",
            "Answer": "no",
            "AnswerCheck": "correct"
          },
          {
            "Num": "3.",
            "Answer": "perhaps",
            "AnswerCheck": "incorrect"
          },
          {
            "Num": "4.",
            "Answer": "all of the above",
            "AnswerCheck": "incorrect"
          },
          {
            "Num": "5.",
            "Answer": "i don't know",
            "AnswerCheck": "incorrect"
          },
          {
            "Num": "6.",
            "Answer": "none of your business",
            "AnswerCheck": "incorrect"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

### Code (need help with the nested page.$$eval(...) function):

```
    const scraped_post_test = async (page) => {

    const courseUNID = await page.$eval("#8888", element => element.getAttribute("id"));

    const qCount = await page.$$eval("#8888 > div.question > div.q-label", elements => {
        return elements.length
    });

    const qLabel = await page.$$eval("#8888 > div.question > div.q-label", elements => {
        return elements.map(element => element.textContent)
    });

    const qQuestion = await page.$$eval("#8888 > div.question > div.q-question", elements => {
        return elements.map(element => element.textContent)
    });

    const qPossibleAnswersArray = await page.$$eval("#8888 > div.question > div.q-choices", elements => {
        /*** nested iteration here? ***/
        const answersArray = [
            {
                "Num": "1.",
                "Answer": "a long way",
                "AnswerCheck": "correct"
            },
            {
                "Num": "2.",
                "Answer": "something else",
                "AnswerCheck": "incorrect"
            },
            ...
            ]
        return answersArray
    });

    let qArray = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < qCount; i++) {
        let testQObj = {};
        testQObj.testQLabel = qLabel[i];
        testQObj.testQ = qQuestion[i];
        testQObj.testQAnswerChoiceCount = qPossibleAnswersArray.length;
        testQObj.testQPossibleAnswers = qPossibleAnswersArray;
        await qArray.push(testQObj)
    }

    return {
        courseUNID,
        qCount,
        qArray
    }
}

module.exports = { scraped_post_test }
```

Answer (score 0):

I can get you started:

```
page.$$eval('.course-wrapper', divs => divs.map(div => {
  let questions = [...div.querySelectorAll('.question')]

  return {
    courseUNID: div.id,
    qCount: questions.length,
    qArray: questions.map(q => {

      let [label, question, choices] = [...q.querySelectorAll('.q-label', '.q-question', '.q-choices')]

      return {
        testQLabel: label.innerText,
        ...

      }
    })
  }
}))
```

Comment: Thank you! I'll give it a try.